# MySQL: Trying to return NULL values in a ER model, but not having any luck

Tags: mysql, null

I have created a realistic table set using the ER model for MySQL.  I am attempting to do joins, but seem to either be missing something, or not doing them correctly in order to produce NULL values. Below are my created tables:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| FilmNumber     | char(3)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| FilmName       | varchar(60) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| OpeningDate    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TopBilledActor | char(60)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Genre          | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CriticSiteNumber | char(3)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CriticSiteName   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CriticName       | char(50)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| FilmNumber       | char(3) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| CriticSiteNumber | char(3) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| OverallScore     | int(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My question is, what type of join query would I need in order to produce NULL values, or does something in my table need to be modified because each of the queries I attempt do not return those values.

Comment: An example of what you want your data to look like would go a long way.

Comment: I am new to coding. My professor stated he wants our tables to produce null values using joins. I have done; right joins from G and FC where f.filmnumber=Fc.filmnumber, and did not receive any nulls. Are null values supposed to be implemented into the original table?

Comment: F and FC*. I have also tried left joins and still nothing different

Comment: How would I know? All you've provided is schema... You haven't specified what you're trying to query.

Comment: I wish I could give more information but all we discussed in class was how to implement joins. He asked us to create joins that produce null values. I truly don't know what specific queries.

Comment: Joins of what? What's the end result that you want to see?

Comment: Are we joining all three tables? In what order? On what fields?

Comment: I'm assuming to produce null values in the critic site number since that is truly the only field that doesn't connect to each of the movies in the database. So joins table f and FC and seeing potentially what critic site numbers haven't reviews a certain film

Comment: Again I wish I had more information to give. My professor literally said, create some good join queries based on your database that produce nulls.

Comment: `SELECT NULL FROM F JOIN FC` is a query with a `JOIN` producing `NULL` values. My educated guess says your professor wants to see a `LEFT JOIN` or a `RIGHT JOIN`, but given above information (and also pointed out by others), your question is very unclear

Comment: He stated that he wanted to see joins. Left and right joins would probably be what he's looking for.

Comment: So I just talked to him, and he stated that left and right joins are exactly what he's looking for. So the join. I attempted was; SELECT FilmName, CriticSiteNumber,OverallScore FROM F RIGHT JOIN FC on F.FilmNumber=FC.FilmNumber GROUP BY FilmNumber. This query did not produce any nulls I'm assuming because for every instance of a FilmNumber, there was a review. Should I create the joins on different constraints?

Comment: Can anyone see what I'm coding and help?